Health risks concerning use of furniture exposed to mould
I am about to buy a piece of second hand furniture. The wardrobe was stored in a room which recently was affected by water damage (it is a showroom not a basement room).
Water damage occured in the ceiling of the room. Since onset of water damage four weeks have passed. A specialist inspected the water damage and detected mould growth, further testing is required to identify the specie.
The wardrobe did not have direct contact with the affected area on the ceiling (e.g. 1.5 m distance).
Now I am asking myself if there are health risks when using the wardrobe in a bedroom.
Specifically my questions are:

Is it possible for fungus material, eg. spores to transfer to the
wardrobe and cause further mould growth even if the condition of
elevated humidity no longer is met?
Could fungus material, e.g. spores transferred to the surface of the object pose a health risk (regarding concentration)?


Remember that we have a one question per post policy and the one about showing your own research.  The biology part would seem to be about mold growth in reduced-humidity conditions and dry rot should give you place to where to start. Health risks of mold would be on-topic on our [medicalsciences.se] site - and are very relative, Some people are sensitive, some not. Remember to show your researches there too.
